# Is there a way to specify TypedValue in ObjectAnimator for textSize?

Tags: android, textview, objectanimator

I have a **TextView** and I want to animate it's **textSize**. This is the code for **animating the textSize using the ObjectAnimator**.

```
    val newSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size)
    val animator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(tv_text, "textSize", newSize)
    animator.duration = 200
    animator.start()
```

The problem with this is that `resources.getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size)`returns a text size value in pixel, and it appears that the ObjectAnimator is defaulting to using a sp value, **this makes the final animated size much bigger than expected**.

If I change

```
val newSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size)
```

to

```
val newSize = resources.getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size) / (resources.displayMetrics.densityDpi.toFloat() / DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT)
```

Then, it will give the correct final animated size because the second one will get the sp value instead of pixel value.

If I change the textSize without animation, I can specify the TypedValue like this:

```
tv_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, resources.getDimension(R.dimen.selected_text_size))
```

So, is there a way to specify the **TypedValue** when animating the **textSize** using **ObjectAnimator**?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know,you can't do that directly.But you can inherit TextView and add a method "setTextSizePixel"

```
fun setTextSizePixel(size: Float) {
    setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, size)
}
```

then replace the TextView needs px text size animation with MyTextView
and use ObjectAnimator animate the textSizePixel property of MyTextView:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(myTextView, "textSizePixel", oldSizePx, newSizePx)
       .apply {
            duration = 3000
            start()
       }
```

Or use ObjectAnimator's parent class ValueAnimator to achieve this by adding code in just one place:

```
ValueAnimator.ofFloat(oldSizePx, newSizePx).apply {
     addUpdateListener { updatedAnimation ->
         tv_text.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, updatedAnimation.animatedValue as Float)
     }
     duration = 3000
     start()
}
```

Comment: The ObjectAnimator was a great solution for me. Thanks for this.